# "creat" function gives wrong permissions

Tags: c, unix, permissions, file-permissions

My code is as follows:

```
#include "unistd.h"
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BSIZE 50

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int f1, f2;
    char buf[BSIZE];

    f1 = open(argv[1], 0x0001, 0);
    f2 = creat(argv[2], 0777);

    read(f1, buf, BSIZE);
    write(f2, buf, BSIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

When I create a file named 'a' and use the compiled program with command

```
./a.out a b
```

It creates a file with the contents of 'a' indeed. But my problem is, its permissions are `-rwxr-xr-x`. It does not give write permissions to group and others. Moreover, when I change the function to `creat(argv[2], 0022);`
then the permission would become all 0 s `----------`.

Is there anything wrong with the `creat` function? Because `chmod` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File creation uses two combined access permissions:

1. the one you provided through `creat` or `open`
2. and the process mask, aka `umask`

`umask` gives some final control to the user of your program by masking some bits to protect created files having some unexpected accesses. In general, `umask` equals to `022` means that write access is removed for group and others, i.e. users don't want more than `rwxr-xr-x`.

Then when you reclaim 0777 it is masked (and) with `~umask` here `0755` giving `0755`.
When you reclaim `022` is is masked (and) with `0755` giving `000`.

Comment: Your explanation of 'umask' satisfied my question very well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Files created by `open`, `creat`, `fopen`, etc. get mode bits masked off with the default `umask`.  You probably have a `umask` of `022`, which is a relaxed default value. Changing the `umask` to `0` would be very risky.  The correct approach is  to use `chmod` explicitly to override this default and make your file writable by group members and others.